# Customize Navigation in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, configuration, sharepoint-2010, navigation

This should be my navigation tree:

```
Root Site (NavigationExample)
TOP - 1
            Web Page - 1.P1
            Web Site - 2
                        Web Site - 2.1
                                    Web Site - 2.1.1
                                    Web Page - 2.1.P1
                                    Web Page - 2.1.P2
                        Web Site - 2.2
                        Web Page - 2.P1
TOP - 2 
            Web Site – 1
                        Web Site - 1.1
                                    Web Site - 1.1.1
                                    Web Page - 1.1.P1 
                        Web Site - 1.2
            Web Site - 2
                        Web Site - 2.1
```

How can I customize a left hand navigation with at least 3 level? I have my top navigation (TOP-1; TOP-2) which is displayed on the top of the page (horizontal).

Now I’d like to have a left hand navigation (only from the active top nav). If TOP-2 is active then only the children of TOP-2 should be displayed.

I’m new to sharepoint, where can i collect the navigation element and how should i edit my masterpage?

Any help would be appreciated

thx